# scons with distcc?

Tags: scons, distcc

What's the correct way of using scons with distcc?
The obvious way of using CC="distcc g++" or CXX doesn't work.

Did anyone ever succeed in combining the two?

Thanks!

Comment: I know nothing about `scons` but did you have a look into [its documentation](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/c2092.html) ?

Comment: Yep, I did. I've ran into several workarounds that suggested modifying the scons source code. Problem is, I don't have the right permissions to modify it, and I'm looking for the standard way of running them both, if one exists.

Comment: You can make a link to `distcc` from `gcc` and put that link early in your `PATH` as suggested by `distcc` man page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you configured CC or CXX via an environment variable? [SCons doesn't pollute its default environment with variables from the calling environment](http://scons.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Why_doesn.27t_SCons_find_my_compiler.2BAC8-linker.2BAC8-etc..3F_I_can_execute_it_just_fine_from_the_command_line.). However, you may initialize the SCons environment from the OS environment (or preferably a subset of it):

```
import os
env = Environment(ENV = os.environ)
env.Program('yourprogram.cpp')
```

Alternatively, this could also work (haven't used SCons in a long time):

```
env = Environment(CXX='distcc g++')
env.Program('yourprogram.cpp')
```

Have a look at the [man page](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html) for an overview of all the variables used in SCons.