# How to run distcc pump include-server from within Scons

Tags: python, scons, distcc

One of the features of distcc version 3 is [pump mode](http://distcc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/web/man/pump_1.html) which allows the slave servers to preprocess as well as compile code from the master. From the shell, this works great for me.

My issue is that I cannot figure out a reliable way to integrate pump mode into an SCons build. I want to:

- Check if distcc's include_server exists (not part of the question, just info)
- Check if distcc's hostlist has `.+,lzo,cpp` hosts required by pump (not a question, info)
- Launch the `include_server` as if I were to run `pump --startup` from the shell.
- Need to catch INCLUDE_SERVER_PORT/PID/DIR and put them into build environment
- build as normal with distcc
- Kill the `include_server` as with `pump --shutdown`

There seem to be two approaches, using `SCons.compat._subprocess` or somehow importing `include_server`. I've experimented and googled, but there seems to be no documentation on this use case.

Note: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025988/scons-with-distcc) addresses "plain" distcc, which works well. I'm specifically addressing pump mode.

Comment: There's a set of extensions for SCons called swtoolkit that looks like it might support it: https://code.google.com/p/swtoolkit. The specific file that seems to implement some of the bits is here: https://code.google.com/p/swtoolkit/source/browse/trunk/site_scons/site_tools/distcc.py?r=68.